# I'm trying to show the Model instead of a dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So basically once the user clicks on the module for create, I would want it to show the module shown instead of a drop down list for selection.

---

```
@model Module1.Models.Learn

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Learn</legend>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModuleId, "Module") 
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ModuleId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModuleId)
      </div>
```

---

Above is my Create View for Learning Outcome.

---

```
@model Module1.Models.Module

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Learning Outcome : @Model.Code</h2>
<br /
```

---

This is the Details View for my Learning Outcome. I tried using the code "@Module.Code" to portray in my Create View but was unsuccessful. Is there another way for me to have the same result in the create view?

---

My Module Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Module1.Models
{
   public class Module
{
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int LecturerId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Lecturer Lecturer { get; set; }

    public List<Reference> References { get; set; }
    public List<Assessment> Assessments { get; set; }//new
    public List<Front> Fronts { get; set; }
    public List<Learn> Learns { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

}
}
```

---

My Learn Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Module1.Models
{
    public class Learn
    {
    public int LearnId { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string LearnText { get; set; }
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
    public bool E { get; set; }
    public bool F { get; set; }
    public bool G { get; set; }
    public bool H { get; set; }
    public bool I { get; set; }
    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }

}
}
```

---

Comment: Not clear what your question is. What do you mean _once the user clicks on the module for create_? In which view, what element is clicked?

Comment: Its a link from the Details View to go to Create View @StephenMuecke

Comment: You don't have any links in your `Details` view. Do you mean you want to know how to render a link that redirects to the `Create` view?

Comment: Nope. I am trying to figure out how to change my dropdown list to just a label where the number is gotten from the ter @Model.Code.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want a dropdown or not (why render it if you don't want one)? If you do, what do you want to render in it (your usage currently makes no sense) Are you trying to display a collection of `Module` items and display the value of `Module.Code`, but bind its `ID` property to `Learn.ModuleID`?

Comment: Yes i want to change the drop down list. I want to display the current module selected.

Comment: This is able to be done on my Details View by using @Model.Code but unable to be done on my Create View

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to include the models for both `Module` and `Learn` so I can give you an answer

Comment: Is there any other things needed to assist you in helping me @StephenMuecke ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your GET method for create you need to generate a `SelectList` that represents the options you want to render in the dropdown. Ideally you should be using a view model to represent what you want to display/edit, but in this example, I'll just assign in to `ViewBag`

```
var modules = // call database to get all the modules
ViewBag.ModuleList = new SelectList(modules, "ModuleId", "Code");
```

View

```
@model Module1.Models.Learn
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  ....
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModuleID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ModuleList, "-please select-")
  ....
}
```

or if your using a view model (which you should, refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)) then it would be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModuleID, Model.ModuleList, "-please select-")
```

Note the value of property `Module.Code` will be the display text, and the value of property `Module.ModuleId` will be bound to the `Learn.ModuleID` property.  If you set the value of `Learn.ModuleID` in the controller before passing it to the view, then the text for that `Module` will be displayed, otherwise the "-please select-" option will be selected.

Note **ALWAYS** use strongly typed helpers - `DropDownListFor()` not `DropDownList()`

**Edit**

Based on further comments by OP, to display the value as 'readonly'. In the controller, get the `Code` value for the `Module` and assign to a view model or `ViewBag` property

```
var module = db.Modules.Where(m => m.ModuleId == learn.ModuleId).FirstOrDefault();
if (module != null)
{
  ViewBag.Code = module.Code;
}
```

and in the view

```
<div>@ViewBag.Code</div>
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Code) // if using a view model
```

and if you want to post back the value as well, include a hidden input for the `ModuleID`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModuleId)
```

Comment: public ActionResult Create(int ID)
        {
            ViewBag.ModuleId = new SelectList(db.Modules, "ModuleId", "Code");
            Learn model = new Learn();
            model.ModuleId = ID;
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: No. `ViewBag.ModuleList = new SelectList(db.Modules, "ModuleId", "Code");` Your assigning the options `ViewBag.ModuleList` which is then used by `@Html.DropDownListFor()` to render the options in the `<select>`. You cant assign the `SelectList` to the same property your binding to.

Comment: I received an error saying

Module1.Models.Learn does not contain a definition for 'ModuleList' and no extension method 'ModuleList' accepting a first argument of type 'Module1.Models.Learn' could be found.

A solution the project gave me was to create a ModuleList stub in my Learn Model.

Comment: Look at my answer. You not using a view model so it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModuleID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ModuleList, "-please select-")`

Comment: Is it because i'm not using a view model?

Comment: Is there a way for me to change it from dropdown to Label or something that cannot be change by the user?

Comment: Sure. I'll update answer shortly (I was confused by you question)

Comment: sorry for this part `m => m.ModuleId == learn.ModuleId` the learn is gotten from where?

Comment: Looking at your last question, I assume you are doing something like `public ActionResult Create(int ID) { Learn model = new Learn(); model.ModuleID = ID; ...` so it could be `m => m.ModuleId == ID` or `m => m.ModuleId == model.ModuleID`

Comment: Okayy thank you again for your help. You have been great help to me.

Comment: Mr Stephen I received this error when creating. `A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = FK_dbo.Learns_dbo.Modules_ModuleId ]` I figured it was because now that the Label has become a label it cause this error. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Did you add the hidden input (last line of my answer)?

Comment: Where is that supposed to be added? Inside the same View?

Comment: I put @HTML.HiddenFor(m=>m.ModuleId) is that the problem?